# Create a circular Image avatar with child circle as status

Tags: html, css

I managed to create a circular avatar using CSS now I want to add another circle located at the bottom of the image so that I can create a status div for the user, similar to Skype or other messaging applications, the problem is I don't know how to make it overlap one another.

here is my code.

```css
.img-circle-small {
      width: 53px;
      height:55px;
      border-top-left-radius: 50% 50%;
      border-top-right-radius: 50% 50%;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 50%;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 50%;
      border: 2px solid #CCC;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
  
  .status{
      width: 16px;
      height:16px;
      border-top-left-radius: 50% 50%;
      border-top-right-radius: 50% 50%;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 50%;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 50%;
      border: 2px solid #CCC;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
      background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj7eP.jpg`enter code here`" alt="avatar" class="img-circle-small">
<div class="status">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this easily with `position: relative` and `position: absolute`.

```css
.img-circle-small {
      width: 53px;
      height:55px;
      border-top-left-radius: 50% 50%;
      border-top-right-radius: 50% 50%;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 50%;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 50%;
      border: 2px solid #CCC;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
  
  .status{
      width: 16px;
      height:16px;
      border-top-left-radius: 50% 50%;
      border-top-right-radius: 50% 50%;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 50%;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 50%;
      border: 2px solid #CCC;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
      background-color: green;

      position: absolute;

    }

  .temp{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .topLeft{
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
  }
  .bottomRight{
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="temp">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj7eP.jpg`enter code here`" alt="avatar" class="img-circle-small">
  <span class="status topLeft">&nbsp</span>
</div>
<div class="temp">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj7eP.jpg`enter code here`" alt="avatar" class="img-circle-small">
  <span class="status bottomRight">&nbsp</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thanks, so I need a temp to wrap both of the elements thanks!

Comment: @Sarotobi you don't need to wrap the elements, see my answer.

Comment: Ok got it! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to `.img-circle-small`

```
  position:relative
```

Add this to `.status`

```
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  z-index: 1;
```

And add this pseudo-element as an option:

```
.status::before {
   content: '8';
   color: #eee;
   font-size:.25em;
   padding-left:4px;
 }
```

### Demo

```css
.img-circle-small {
      width: 53px;
      height:55px;
      border-top-left-radius: 50% 50%;
      border-top-right-radius: 50% 50%;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 50%;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 50%;
      border: 2px solid #CCC;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
      position: relative;
    }
  
  .status{
      width: 16px;
      height:16px;
      border-top-left-radius: 50% 50%;
      border-top-right-radius: 50% 50%;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 50%;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 50%;
      border: 2px solid #CCC;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
      background-color: green;
      position: absolute;
      top: 8px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .status::before {
       content: '8';
       color: #eee;
       font-size:.25em;
       padding-left:4px;
     }
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj7eP.jpg`enter code here`" alt="avatar" class="img-circle-small">
<div class="status">&nbsp</div>
```